# Having a UI layer and presentation layer

Tags: asp.net

> Let's say I'm on a list page and I
>   page to, say, page 10. Then I select
>   a record on that page and redirect to detail
>   page. After that, I click on the edit
>   to redirect to the edit page.
>
> After I update the record I'm redirected back to
>   the detail page. I, then, press back
>   to go back list to continue my browsing from
>   where I left off. The key here is
>   where I left off in the list which is
>   page 10.

What is the best way to handle this?

Initially, I put a hidden field called page number in each of the webforms and pass it along with the querystring back and forth. Seemed like a lot or a bit redundant checking the querystring on each page and passing it.

I was wondering if there are some other ways. for instance, I've been reading about a separation between the UI and the presentation layer is a good idea (for larger scale apps). To me I understand it as all click handler events will yield control over to the presentation layer which is just a plain class?

Is this correct? Also, is the presentation layer suppose to implement something particular? I know this could probably be saved in session but could someone humor me and show me how to use a presentation layer to handle this (I know it would be overkill but is it possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is *THE* best way. Everything depends of what you achieve to do, ie. the requirements of the whole project.

After all, according to the description, I don't even understand why are you having three pages to do a single thing. By the way, ASP.NET data controls handle mostly everything for you, so you don't even have to ask yourself how to do this (except if you have serious reasons to avoid ASP.NET controls).

For example, a simple `<asp:ListView />` will let you list items page per page and show details when a single item is selected. Edition of an element is also quite easy.

Comment: thru "inheritance" is the reason for the 3 pages to accomplish this. Inheritance of an existing project that is.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is well... large and could span multiple blog posts to give a complete understanding of UI Design Patterns.

I have a small example of MVP with Asp.Net here: [What is the best way to reuse pages from one website in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320801/what-is-the-best-way-to-reuse-pages-from-one-website-in-another/321054#321054)

However, it is not exhaustive. If you really want information on this you should do some looking into a framework such as [WebForms MVP](http://webformsmvp.com/), or [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It is a framework which goes on top of ASP.NET to do the separation between the presentation layer and business layer.

Comment: likewise, i'd suggest that - however, i think the question is related to winforms and how to achieve it there. no such thing as a one line win :)

Comment: @jim: the question was tagged as asp.net.

Comment: Maybe it's not appropriate place to ask you this : how much does it take to learn ASP.NET MVC for a person who has 2 years ASP.NET Web Form Experience ?

Comment: @Mostafa: I charge $100/hour, j/k. Personally I started with reading ASP.NET Quickly, but I'm sure others will suggest other books. Short quick read, only a few hundred pages.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, what you are describing is a very good example of the perfect place to use Asp.Net Dynamic Data.

It's incredibly easy and powerful, and easy to modify once you dig into it a bit. I'd start with the videos here: http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata

I've been using this more and more on every project, for at least the simple CRUD portion of it.  I really can't express how much I love this tool now that I'm used to it.